# Separate numbers from string to array

Tags: c, arrays, string, numbers

Please help me. I need to separate the numbers from the string so that they are written to the array from the beginning of the array.

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000

int main() {
    char str[MAX];
    int x;
    int arr[MAX];

    printf("Input: ");
    gets(str);
    for (x = 0; str[x] != '\0'; x++) {
        if (str[x] >= '0' && str[x] <= '9') {
            arr[x] = (str[x] - 48);
        }
    }
    for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
        printf("Output: %d \n", arr[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean extract digits?

Comment: This is an example of what input and output looks like. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SzQfuHaw_yHiQMROYUnag9kEYxfsrmnD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you write the expected output in the question ? => like an input-output example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in `arr[x]` many of elements in arr fields are left, for example when  you're adding 
your first element to array, int X might be 10.

so you got wrong output look:

```
   gets(str);
    int i = 0;
    for (x = 0; str[x] != '\0'; x++) {
        if (str[x] >= '0' && str[x] <= '9') {
            { arr[i] = (str[x] - 48);
            i++; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `gets_s(str);` is no fix for `gets(str)` problems, `48` should be changed to `'0'`.

Comment: @chqrlie sorry about get_s it wasn't about problem.I wrote codes in c++ compiler(visual) which always give me this strange error to get_s instead of gers so it's kind of my habit to wrote get_s, but thanks for saying I edited it. But 48 is right because `ascii code(Dec)`of``'0'` is 48 and since he is using decimal bits I don't see why it should change to `'0'`

Comment: `'0'` is better than hard coding ASCII value `48`: it is more portable and more readable. `gets(str)` must be replaced with `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)` here. The newline is not a problem.